# How to decode CSV to Array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

How to convert this CSV object to array or JSON .

Thanks

```
var obj = 3;ID;NAME;
```

Comment: Thats not CSV or even valid JavaScript ... Please edit & add detail to your question.  (What is `$.csv`?)

Comment: This doesn't look anything like CSV.

Comment: I think your bigger problem is how to use JavaScript. Go follow a starting tutorial on its syntax please.

Comment: You proabably forgot to include the jquery-csv file in your html. <script src="//jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

Comment: nope, I realized that I do not hold such a complex solution,

Comment: i really need classes of javascript. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a string, and then you can use the split function, as in:

```
var array= "3;ID;NAME".split(";");
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).  Note you can split on any character, semicolon (as you have above), or if true CSV, a comma too.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really be rolling your own code to parse csv unless the format is very simple. You're going to end up with a massive amount of extra work to handle all the special cases that will arise.

You can use jQuery and jquery-csv:

Include the scripts:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
```

Decode like this:

```
var csv = "heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5\nvalue1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1\nvalue1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2";
jsObject = $.csv.toObjects(csv)
```

Example in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xS1IRNwNCwvLBKzpliBU?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split a comma delimited string into an array you can do it as such:

```
var csv = "a,string,seperated,by,comma"
var array = csv.split(",");
```

Comment: This is at some point going to end bad. What if the value contains a comma? The usual way to handle this, is to put the value in double quotes. This method can't handle this.

Read section 2 from this article: http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/07/08/7-things-never-code/

My suggestions is to just use a library like jquery.

Comment: CSV can be separated by semicolon.

Comment: @Xerardoo then split the string by ";" instead of ','